# Fast way to get index of non-blank values in row/column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Let's say we have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 3.0, 1: 2.0, 2: None}, 'b': {0: 10.0, 1: None, 2: 8.0}, 'c': {0: 4.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 6.0}})

     a     b    c
0  3.0  10.0  4.0
1  2.0   NaN  2.0
2  NaN   8.0  6.0
```

I need to get a dataframe with, for each row, the column names of all non-NaN values.
I know I can do the following, which produces the expected outupt:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().index), axis=1)

   0  1    2
0  a  b    c
1  a  c  NaN
2  b  c  NaN
```

Unfortunately, this is quite slow with large datasets. Is there a faster way?

Getting the row indices of non-Null values of each column could work too, as I would just need to transpose the input dataframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
m = df.notna()
a = m.mul(df.columns).where(m).to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame(a[np.arange(len(a))[:,None], np.argsort(~m, axis=1)],
                   index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
   0  1    2
0  a  b    c
1  a  c  NaN
2  b  c  NaN
```

##### timings

On 30k rows x 3 columns:

```
# numpy approach
6.82 ms ± 1.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# pandas apply
7.32 s ± 553 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Hello mozway, may I ask what `[:, None]` does in `a[np.arange(len(a))[:, None]]`? In fact it turns it into a 3 dimensional array. But I couldn't figure out why we need it here.

Comment: @Anoushiravan this is to transform the 1D range indexer into a 2D single column. It's a numpy trick to index with an array combined with the `np.argsort(~m, axis=1)`.

Comment: @mozway I noticed that sometimes the script doesn't preserve the original order of the indexes. Is there a way to fix that? Thank you